# How to repair damaged mkv file on mac

Tags: macos

I tried [Meteorite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meteorite/). It doesn't work, just keep crashing. Any other way I can fix the damaged .mkv file on Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try extracting video and audio with MKVToolnix and re-muxing with the same tool.